# Bluetooth communication with Mono C#

Tags: c#, mono, bluetooth, rfcomm

I'm trying to establish a serial connection between the PC (Linux 32bit) and an hardware device via Bluetooth.

I've already tested the system using cutecom. It works. Baud 115200, `/dev/rfcomm0` etc ...

Now I'm trying to create a client software with Mono to be able to implement a communication protocol.  I have tested the `SerialPort` Object:

```
    SerialPort mySerial;
    mySerial = new SerialPort("/dev/rfcomm0", 115200);
    mySerial.Open();
    mySerial.ReadTimeout = 1000;
```

It doesn't work.  I've tested the system via a wired serial connection, on `/dev/ttyACM0`, and it worked. So I don't think this is the way.

I've tried to use `FileStream` and `StreamReader` but throws an `Exception.IO: WIN32 IO returned 997`.

How use a serial connection with a Bluetooth device with Mono C#?

Comment: How does it not work?  Have you called mySerial.Read(); Have you tried mySerial.DataReceived+=new    ( etc ).

Comment: When working with serial communications as a matter of good practice it's worth setting stop-bit and parity values to some established default values.  And always start off with a low baud rate value, and up the speed when you're sure everything is working.  Example here a good starting point, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Comment: Why do you want to do serial operations?

Answer (score 0):

As of bluez 5, [dbus is the preferred method](http://blog.mrgibbs.io/bluetooth-pairing-with-bluez-and-dbus/) of interacting with bluez vs interop.  There is a series of posts on this topic [here](http://blog.mrgibbs.io/get-on-d-bus/), basically it involves connecting to dbus and doing the following.

- Registering a Pairing agent
- Pairing the device
- Registering a serial / rfcomm profile
- Signaling the device you want to connect and waiting for the connection on your profile object
- Opening a stream from the returned file descriptor object.

Once you have the stream, you can perform all the usual read/write operations on the stream just like you would if you had opened it as a serial port.

Comment: The BlueZ DBus implementation works with proxies, which form the core abstraction to just about anything Bluetooth related: peripheral devices, bluetooth controller (adapter), GATT characteristics if you're using LE, and so on. DBus objects publish an interface with methods and properties that should be used. I don't know what OP's intent is with the serial / rfcomm profile, but writes can be managed in a different way using DBus.